# generate_series() - how to use it to populate multiple columns in a table?

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, generate-series

I have a table with the following structure:

```
widgetnumber - text
dd  - text 
refnumber - text
```

widgetnumber and refnumber need to be populated with the same value... one that's generated using generate_series.
dd will be a static value that's set once.

I have the following code:

```
INSERT INTO widgets(widgetnum, dd, refnum)
SELECT i
FROM generate_series(100, 150) AS t(i), 
'somestaticstring',
SELECT p
FROM generate_series(100, 150) AS t(p);
```

But I must have a syntax error somewhere because this is not working.
I'm getting the following error:

```
psql:addwidgets.sql:11: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'somestaticstring'"
LINE 4: 'somestaticstring',
        ^
```

**What I've tried**

I've tried to change the single quotes around the static text to double.  I've also tried this:

```
INSERT INTO widgets(widgetnum, dd, refnum)
SELECT i
FROM generate_series(100, 150) AS t(i), 
SELECT 'somestaticstring',
SELECT p
FROM generate_series(100, 150) AS t(p);
```

But that also fails with a syntax error.

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in `text` columns?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can treat this just like a normal INSERT SELECT

```
INSERT INTO widgets
SELECT generate_series(100,150), 'somestaticstring', generate_series(100,150)
```

Comment: @Happydevdays: While multiple set-returning functions in the `SELECT` list are allowed in Postgres (unlike standard SQL), it's not a good idea. Surprising behavior if not all return the same number of rows. Move set-returning functions to the `FROM` clause whenever possible. Consider a_horse's answer.

Comment: I prefer the solution from *a_horse*: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41305292/967621 . It avoids repetitive calls to `generate_series`, thus it is more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). This is in addition to the comment from @ErwinBrandstetter.

Answer (score 22):

Make it part of the select statement:

```
INSERT INTO widgets(widgetnum, dd, refnum)
SELECT i::text, 'somestaticstring', i::text
FROM generate_series(100, 150) AS t(i),
```

Comment: I am curious, what does the "AS t(i)" bit do exactly ?

Comment: @EllertvanKoperen: it's a [table alias](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES)

Comment: Aha, so it names the generated table t and the single column i, gotcha. Thanks, very helpfull.